# How to randomize file paths for shard distribution?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

[Google docs state](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices)

> Avoid using sequential filenames such as timestamp-based filenames if
>   you are uploading many files in parallel

Filename here means **the full file path** excluding bucket name

> Forward slashes in objects have no special meaning to Cloud Storage,
>   as there is no native directory support.

[Advice online](https://medium.com/@duhroach/google-cloud-storage-sequential-file-names-f1ba1205c6a8) has said to add a filehash to the filename itself.
Eg. `filenamehash-filename`

However, in a folder structure the full filenames would be:

```
same_filepath/hash1-file1
same_filepath/hash1-file2
same_filepath/hash1-file3
```

So although the final filename is randomized, the base path is still the same thus not distributed into different shards.

Does length of the static filepath affect likelihood of better distribution?

Is there some optimal filepath length to remain under so random filenames will still affect shard distribution?

Eg. `f1/f2/hash-filename` vs `long_folder_name1/long_folder_name_2/hash-filename`

Is there another approach to this that needs to be popularized?

I know Google Cloud Storage (like s3) is not meant as a native filesystem but keeping a separate index/directory of storage files seems like overengineering.

Comment: What is your environment? Here I mean what are the Cloud Storage Objects used for and where do they come from? If you just have a simple bucket with files for your website, don't worry about sharding. If this is an IoT setup with millions of files being uploaded and processed constantly in short time periods, sharding is very important. In the latter case, use a random number at the beginning of the object name. It is the object name beginning string that has the most effect on sharding and not the length. Review hashing and collisions to determine a strategy that fits your requirements.

Comment: Files come from different cloud functions.  ~1000 files / minute uploaded to ~10 different file paths in the same bucket.  Using a random number at the beginning of a filepath would cause complete file structure chaos.

Comment: What file system structure do you need? Edit your question with details. To implement sharding, stop thinking file system. Start thinking a bucket of objects. Without exact architecture details, your question has little chance for a good answer.

Comment: I think that all depends on the quantity of files that you are uploading to the same "directory" for example if you are uploading a lot of files to the same directory you can experience degradation on the uploads, but if you are uploading files using differents "directories" you can achieve the shard distribution. The medium article mentions "Which is very helpful if the files are in different directories, since each one can be properly distributed to different shards."